# backdrop-filter vs filter

Tags: css, css-filters

Recently I found 2 similar properties and can't figure out what's the differences between them.

Can you explain me please? Why does properties `backdrop-filter` and `filter` exists at the same time?

As I see ([here](https://drafts.fxtf.org/filter-effects/#FilterProperty) and [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects-1/)) they do the same things:

- `grayscale()`
- `sepia()`
- `saturate()`
- `hue-rotate()`
- `invert()`
- `opacity()`
- `brightness()`
- `contrast()`
- `drop-shadow()`

When we should use `backdrop-filter` and when just `filter`?

caniuse.com says ([here](https://caniuse.com/#search=filter) and [here](https://caniuse.com/#search=backdrop-filter)) that modern browsers supports `filter` much better than `backdrop-filter`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to https://iamvdo.me/en/blog/advanced-css-filters, filter will affect the element itself, and backdrop-filter will affect the elements beneath the element within the bounding box of the element. It looks like a page with a black body and an element with backdrop-filter: invert(); would turn that part of the body white.

```
backdrop-filter: invert();
```

This codepen shows that to be the case, in Chrome, with Experimental Web Platform features enabled in chrome://flags.

https://codepen.io/Jason_B/pen/wpjQGK

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The backdrop-filter property applies the effects behind the selected element. Where the filter property applies the effects to the entire element.

Please take a look at this demo:
https://codepen.io/AbidAlWassie/pen/yLvzLKx

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.backdrop-filter {
  background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/669015/pexels-photo-669015.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1);
  height: 400px;
}

.overlay {
  backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
  height: 100%;
  /* background-color: #ff000091; */
}

.filter {
  background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/669015/pexels-photo-669015.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1);
  filter: blur(2px);
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="backdrop-filter">
    <div class="overlay">
      <h1>backdrop-filter demo:</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem, tenetur molestiae harum numquam nemo consectetur architecto optio asperiores animi debitis non hic fuga expedita vel voluptatibus, facilis possimus est voluptatum iusto quos nostrum tempora ducimus reprehenderit! Nobis facilis aliquid ea ab alias iure ipsam! Repellat, labore. Nostrum dignissimos minus non harum, eos totam, in asperiores magni rerum vero deleniti, expedita voluptatibus suscipit iusto inventore. Sunt tempora enim hic aliquid cupiditate porro vitae amet eum incidunt. Error, repellat! Similique, tempore enim?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
    
  <div class="filter">
    <h1>filter demo:</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem, tenetur molestiae harum numquam nemo consectetur architecto optio asperiores animi debitis non hic fuga expedita vel voluptatibus, facilis possimus est voluptatum iusto quos nostrum tempora ducimus reprehenderit! Nobis facilis aliquid ea ab alias iure ipsam! Repellat, labore. Nostrum dignissimos minus non harum, eos totam, in asperiores magni rerum vero deleniti, expedita voluptatibus suscipit iusto inventore. Sunt tempora enim hic aliquid cupiditate porro vitae amet eum incidunt. Error, repellat! Similique, tempore enim?</p>
  </div>
```